# Problem With Zuul and eureka in stand alone local tomcat

Tags: spring-boot, microservices

I have created Eureka server and zuul server which runs on port 8761 and 8762 with embedded server perfectly,

But Problem is when i deploy war on local tomcat, eureka server runs perfectly(http://localhost:8080/EurekaServer/).

But zuul is not able to find eureka server when i start zuul war on local tomcat.
Error is : java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect

need to run multiple instances of tomcat on different ports ? if yes, how ?

Comment: Eureka Server Application.properties :
    spring.application.name=eureka-server 
    eureka.instance.hostname=eureka 
    server.port=8761 
    eureka.client.register-with-eureka=false 
    eureka.client.fetch-registry=false

Comment: Zuul Server Application.properties : 
server.port=8762
spring.application.name=zuul-server
eureka.client.register-with-eureka=true
eureka.client.fetch-registry=true
        
#eureka.client.service-url.default-zone= 
http://localhost:8080/EurekaServer/
#eureka.client.service-url.default-zone=http://localhost:8080/EurekaServer/eureka
eureka.client.service-url.default-zone=http://localhost:8761/eureka

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Changing default port of eureka server using spring cloud](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45615866/changing-default-port-of-eureka-server-using-spring-cloud)

Comment: please fix the formatting of your question text. it is difficult to read.